# What steps would you take to make an already finished Layout browser compatible

Tags: css, cross-browser

I know there are a few questions out there regarding what to do to create a website from scratch having browser compatibility in mind,... but what about a finished website? I've been given a website that somebody else designed and it looks sweet in Firefox, but it's awful in any other browser,... everything is all over the place (Yeah, my skills to describe technical problems are amazing), collapsed divs everywhere! That's the biggest issue here, I guess if I can solve that bit I could figure the rest out from that point on.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: a link to said website would help.

Comment: What version of FF? If the CSS and HTML are standards compliant it should render very similarly in any of the current version of browsers. If not, then you would probably be best off starting fresh with good code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you really haven't given any specifics that can be addressed, I would just state that I don't see any shortcut to resolving this.

Ideally, you'll be able to go through and make a list of those techniques that are not compatible with other browsers. If that will be too much work then you are sort of looking at a rewrite.

And this, of course, is the reasons why website developers should be testing on all major browsers as the site is developed.